# R : Re-scale data

Tags: r

I'm using R and the cars data frame.

I want to do a test :

**1/** Scale the "cars" data in cars.scale

**2/** Unscale cars.scale in order to check if I recover "cars" data

I did this but it doesn't work

```
data(cars)
library(DMwR)
cars.scale<- scale(cars)
head(cars)
head(cars.scale)

original_data <- unscale(cars.scale, cars)
```

I obtain this error message :*"Error in -centers : invalid argument to unary operator"*

Could you please help me to understand what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the CRAN manual, you have the answer there. The first argument in the function is "a numeric matrix with the values to un-scale", which is `cars.scale`. The second argument is "an object to which the function `scale()` was applied", which is also `cars.scale`.

```
original_data <- unscale(cars.scale, cars.scale)

#      speed dist
# [1,]     4    2
# [2,]     4   10
# [3,]     7    4
# [4,]     7   22
# [5,]     8   16
```

From the CRAN manual

unscale(vals, norm.data, col.ids)

**Arguments**

**vals** 
A numeric matrix with the values to un-scale

**norm.data**
A numeric and scaled matrix.
This should be an object to which the function scale() was applied.

**col.ids**
The columns of the vals matrix that are to be un-scaled (defaults to all of them).